# Clause ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a select in sql server, i have this table with 2 columns:

```
a   2
b   1
c  100
d   1
a  100
b   1
c   2
d   1
```

I want  ordered it  based on the first column,in this way:

```
a   2
a   100
b   1
b   1
c   2
c   100
d   1
d   1
```

But then j want the rows with secondcolumn=100 be moved at the bottom,so:

```
a   2
b   1
b   1
c   2
d   1
d   1
a  100
c  100
```

I have tried with clause  ORDER BY column1 ASC, (column2=100) ASC,but it didnt work!

Thankyou and greetings.

Comment: Can you show what Select statements you have tried?

Comment: Is "100" some magical value?

Comment: No,is not magic value,but is an example....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
ORDER BY 
CASE 
   WHEN col2>=100 THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END,
col1,
col2
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fad38/2)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you want the rows with 100 in the second column moved to the bottom *first*, and then ordered by the first column:

```
order by (case when col2 = 100 then 1 else 0 end),
         col1
```

Comment: So Parado asnwered the question and you answered the desired result ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tab 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN column2 = 100 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
          END ASC,
          column1 asc
```

Comment: Tankyou,i didnt know this special use of the keyword CASE used with the ORDERBY clause.

Comment: sorry,bur dont'work as i expected ..in fact the result is:

a           2
a          100
b          1
b          1
c          2
c          100
d          1
d          1